# Snort Rule to Alert DNS that has ACK

Tags: snort

What way can i write a rule to alert me of a DNS that has an ACK when it shouldnt? Im quite confused on this.

This is what i see in wireshark `Acknowledgment Number: 0x000001a4 [should be 0x00000000 because ACK flag is not set]`

But i want a rule that will alert me.

This rule below isnt working for me.

`alert tcp any any -> 192.168.10.2 53 (msg:"MALFORMED DNS QUERY"; flags: A; ack:0; sid:10501;)`
The above wont show in my alert log. But if i remove flags: and ack: it will.

Answer (score 1):

When the ACK flag is set the acknowledgment number will never be "0", so this rule will not function as is.

Without "ack:" the only check in the rule is for an ACK flag set (rule header aside). If you are running DNS over TCP you will see the ACK flag set as a normal part of the TCP conversation i.e. each endpoint acknowledging received TCP segments.

What you're seeing in wireshark:

Acknowledgment Number: 0x000001a4 [should be 0x00000000 because ACK flag is not set]

Might be part of the expert info telling you that the acknowledgment number is non-zero when it should be (for instance when a tcp connection is initiated the first packet should only have the SYN flag set.)

I'm really not sure what you are trying to accomplish here.